# JavaScript confirm() crashing with FF 3.6.4

Tags: javascript, firefox, confirm

Yesterday I added a line of JavaScript that uses confirm(), and I was using FireFox 3.6.3 and it was working fine, but today FireFox upgrades to 3.6.4 in the background and the confirm() freezes my browser, although it still works in IE. I suspect it is a FireFox 3.6.4 issue.

I was wondering if that was indeed a FireFox 3.6.4 issue. If anyone could please let me know, that would be great.

Thank you very much,

Rudy

Comment: Post your code or it's unlikely anybody will be able to duplicate or diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

confirm() works as expected here (FF3.6.4 US-en)

Comment: Thank you for your output. I will look more into. I rolled back too 3.6 and it works fine (Safari and IE as well). Thanks though.

Comment: No problem, have you tried, a simple html file that calls confirm() ? if that works perhaps the issues lies with other parts of the code/framework you use and firefox.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried and it crashes as well. Also FireBug crashes on any kind of code. Something went wrong with my install of FireFox 3.6.4, or the plugins mess up with this version, I am not sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't see [any similar issues in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=Firefox&content=confirm), so it's likely that this is not an issue with confirm() itself but, rather with how you're using it.

Can you create a simple, stand-alone test case that reproduces the problem and post it to http://pastie.org so others can test it?  If people are able to reproduce it, than it should be submitted as to Bugzilla.